# Why templates must be defined outside class

Tags: c++

I know that templates must be declared and defined in the same file. But, why I cannot:

```
#ifndef guard
#define guard
template<typename T>
class Test{
   void method(){

   }
}; 
#endif
```

And it is causes compiler error ( not directly but instatantiation template Test in two different place- for example in main() and as field in any class causes error.

It must be defined outside class ( It doesn't cause error like here)

```
#ifndef guard
#define guard
template<typename T>
class Test{
   void method();

}; 
#endif
template<typename T>
void Test<T>::method(){}
```

Why?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You can definitely define member functions of class templates inside the class. Please provide a [mcve] of the actual compilation error you're getting.

Comment: I would not know how to create an error with the first snippet that disappears with the second one

Comment: Delete that compiler... if and only if you are telling the truth...

Comment: Could not reproduce.  1st snippet compiles clean on g++ v5.2.1

Comment: The error you get seems to be related to something else. Can you paste the exact error message? Not that we do not want to help you, but your assumtion is simply wrong (which should help you already, I hope).

Answer (score 1):

Member functions of class templates **can** be defined inline, inside the class template declaration.

The code in the question:

```
template<typename T>
class Test{
   void method(){

   }
};
```

is well formed. Asking why you can't do it is misguided.